# Changing Google Recaptcha language

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

how can I toggle Recaptcha's language depending on which button was clicked?

I got initialization right and button click logs in console language code.

I want to update hl: 'ar' to 'en' or 'ar' depengind which button was clicked.

```
var loadCaptcha = function(){
    grecaptcha.render("recaptcha", {
    sitekey: "xxx",
    theme: "light",
    hl: 'ar'
    });
}
loadCaptcha();


$('.buttons').find('a').on('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault;
    console.log( $(this).data('lang') );
});
```

Comment: `var loadCaptcha = function(lang){
    grecaptcha.render("recaptcha", {
    sitekey: "xxx",
    theme: "light",
    hl: lang
    });
`
`loadCaptcha($(this).data('lang'))` ?

Comment: Also you might have to [reset it](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

Comment: I get: "reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element". You can check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/rolandas/z6Lu0dg5/62/

Comment: I think you should pass `widgetID` to `reset()` method . Can you check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nrpxm17c/8/) please?

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil your example doesn't work

Comment: Any ideas, please? :)

Comment: 5 mins please . I'm updating the plunker

Comment: Hi @Roland Can you check this please ? https://plnkr.co/edit/TyY4fSBy9tjwkxl779dd?p=preview

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil yes, now it works, but there is js error in console: reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil it would be nice to get rid of that error

Comment: Are you getting the error in that plnkr link too?

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil yes, aren't you getting it?

Comment: Ah! Yeah!. I'm getting the error in Chrome and not in FireFox. Let me look at it

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil I'm getting that error even in FireFox